# How can I get rid of cats destroying my landscaping in a natural way?

Tags: pest-control, pests, landscaping

My neighbor's cats love to use my yard, garden, and flower beds as their person toilets. What can I use that is natural, and non-lethal to deter them from using my areas as a litter box. Whatever I use must not damage my flowers, lawn, or garden and must not be harmful to children.

Comment: Cats just are not a problem in the landscape.  They dig little depressions and poo and pee and that is it.  I am completely for indoor cats.  Outdoor cats become everyone's cats.  I watched this little documentary about outdoor domesticated cats that was very illuminating.  Cats make a 'rectangular route' they maintain.  Visiting the same places and becoming very familiarized with their route their true 'home'.  They take care of your rodents and that is a big deal.  What else are they doing that you want to control?

Comment: Pooping and peeing on your property and vegetable garden I've not found to ever be a problem.  Are you actually digging in the soil with your hands and running into kitty poo?  If this is true, get a big cat box, fill with sand.  Clean out once in a while.  Cats will always use a cat box if they have a choice.  I kid you not.  Clumping kitty litter is not at all a good choice.  Perhaps, if you can find this stuff, get alfalfa pellets.  Used to be sold for kitty litter, I thought I found it again as rabbit food but that stuff you could dump on your plant beds to accelerate decomposition of bark

Comment: Mostly the pee and pooping- I'll have to show you a picture of the severity of the situation. It if was one or two cats it wont be such a big, but there are many cats. Causing many holes. And if I am not out there everyday they start to dig up plants, or spraying my blueberries. I have tried coffee grounds and peppermint oil with little luck. While I don't mind having the cats around. Niall has marked this as a duplicate question- and I have gleaned a lot of good information from the link provided.

Comment: And, I have no idea why this is a problem but talking with your neighbors is the first thing to do. You need to give them feedback that their cats are on your property pooping and peeing.  You have a responsibility to tell them this fact.  Otherwise, those cats are also your responsibility and that is not fair to you nor the cats.  Cats are fine indoors. They don't need the big bad dangerous out of doors at all...sure it is fun but cats are adaptable and their owners should provide stimulus right in the home.  As well as cat boxes!  Really, neighbors are being quite selfish.

Comment: Whoa, @TheGrumpyTurtle.  That is a lot more than I've imagined.  I keep my cats indoors but gee, I feed and care for 5 others.  Fed cats don't eat so many baby bunnies.  And I love cats.  Please send a picture.  We could take this to chat most certainly.  I am very big on harmony with animals and cats are my favorites.  So selfish of cat owners.  Especially in a suburban?  Urban?  environment?  Blueberries love acidity, snickers.  Limb them up so the spray doesn't harm the growth or berries.  Those cats are not neutered and that makes me very mad.  Seriously, your neighbors need to be informed

Comment: I appreciate your time stormy. Another reason why this is an issue is that I have little children. And as you may be aware cat poop can contain Toxoplasma gondii, which is toxic to children and pregnant people. I have spoken with a few neighbors but none seem to care. Quite frankly, I do not have the resources (mental, time, financial) to be dealing with cleaning up after other people's pets. Especially, if I need to do it every day so that my plants don't get dug up, or my sprayed.

Comment: I am not getting your comments in order- I am new at thisand dont know what the chat is yet or if I have enough rep to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60153/discussion-between-thegrumpyturtle-and-stormy).

Comment: Well, don't worry about your kids.  (how many you lucky dog)?  Toxoplasma gondii is toxic to pregnant women via the dust from cleaning kitty boxes.  Unless your kids are eating kitty roca, I wouldn't worry about them at all.  The kids I mean.  It is a major bummer to have your plant beds become kitty boxes.  Go talk with your neighbors.  Is that a problem?  I was taught that that is a problem but I did it anyway while living in a development. I was never popular!! There must be something to deter these guys.  I'll check this out.